# How to call external "interactive/TUI" command, interact, and read std output

Tags: vim

I am trying to write my first vim script, so I apologize if this question boils down to not understanding the basics.

The main goal is that I want to call out to an external command from inside vim and read the results back into the file.
I know how to do this with simple shell commands, e.g. `r !ls`. However the command I want to interact with is "interactive".

I don't know if this is a meaningful description. But calling this command in the shell opens a TUI, then after interacting with the TUI the command will exit and put things into standard output. I want to read that standard output back into vim.

Possibly it will help to discuss the specific command, which is `papis` a cli citation manager. If you call, e.g. `papis list --format '{doc[title]} {doc[author]}'` in the shell it will open up a TUI that allows me to filter down and select a document. After selecting the document it will put the title and author into the standard output. This is what I want to read into vim.

However, my first few attempts have not been successful. Trying the naive `:r !papis list` results in an error, even though that command is valid in the shell and would result in the TUI being opened. So I'm obviously missing something.

Can anyone recommend a guide or suggest a possible solution for correctly calling out to TUI-based external commands and reading back their standard output?

Comment: My 1st advice is to remove `vim` from the equation, so to said. Try to learn to manipulate the program **with its stdout redirected** simply from the command line/shell scripts. What OS/shell, btw?

Comment: If `papis` would directly write its UI to `/dev/tty` and only the result output to stdout, it should work just fine. Obviously, it doesn't. If there's an option to interactively edit and then export to a file, you could read that in from Vim. Else, only thing I can imagine (other than modifying `papis` itself) is capturing all output via `tee` (so that you still see the UI, but also have everything recorded), and then fishing out the real output from the end of the record (via `tail` or `sed`), and reading that from Vim.

Comment: @IngoKarkat I've opened an issue on `papis` re `/dev/tty` will see what the main dev says.

Comment: @phd thanks for the tip, I will do some googling about redirecting stdout.